# How to find a parent element width in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **HTML** code like this -

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <input type="text" id="typehead" style="width: 500px;" class="form-control" placeholder="accounts" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="accounts" />
</div>
```

I have to find the width of the parent element having ID **typehead**.

So in this case I have to find width of the div having class **bs-example**.

I can't use **ID** in the upper div so that I can have the width of the element by ID because **I want a re-usable code because it should be used many places in the page**.

What I have done is -

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentNode.parentElement.width;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: You're forgetting style property....instead of .width use .style.width

Comment: Can you please give me a answer in detail ?

Because I am new and I can't understand your word.

Comment: Why are you using both `parentNode` and `parentElement`, and where is `#myLI`, and what do you mean by the parent element having ID `typehead`, that's an input, it has no children? This is just all very unclear?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var x = $("#typehead").parent().width();
```

Comment: This requires jQuery

Answer (score 40):

You can use

```js
function parentWidth(elem) {
    return elem.parentElement.clientWidth;
}
parentWidth(document.getElementById('typehead'));
```

Note that it will throw if you call it with the argument `document.documentElement`. If you want it to return `undefined` instead of throwing, use `parentNode` instead of `parentElement`.

```js
function parentWidth(elem) {
  return elem.parentElement.clientWidth;
}
alert(parentWidth(document.getElementById('typehead')) + 'px');
```

```html
<div class="bs-example">
  <input type="text" id="typehead" style="width: 500px;" class="form-control" placeholder="accounts" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="accounts" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) property:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentNode.parentElement.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

**Update by [Orion user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) (thank you) from the comments to this post:**

> Note this will retrieve the `width` used in the `style` content attribute, which may not be the same as the computed `width`

Comment: Note this will retrieve the `width` used in the `style` content attribute, which may not be the same as the computed `width`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidier example using JQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/srfqko8r/3/

```
<div style="width: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 50px;" id="child">
    </div>
</div>

function GetParentDivWidth(selector){
    return $(selector).parent("div").width();
}

$(function(){
   alert(GetParentDivWidth("#child"));
});
```

Alerts "100"

Answer (score 1):

If you  want a generic function you can use pass the element to check as parameter and use jQuery `closest` and `width`.

Code:

```
function myFunction($el) {
    return $el.closest('div.bs-example').width();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f07uanoh/